# Adicionar prefab pelo código e não pelo inspector

Tags: unity3d

Atualmente o meu jogo possui apenas um tipo de inimigo e quero passar a adicionar outros 3 tipos de inimigo.

Para adicionar um tipo de inimigo fiz o seguinte:

- Criei um empty object e adicionando a esse objecto um box collider 2d com a opção "is trigger" activa e um rigidbody 2d.
- Adicionei ao palco o primeiro inimigo e quando esse inimigo colidir com o objecto que criei acima, um novo inimigo é adicionado. Esse novo inimigo é um prefab.

No meu script tenho o seguinte:

```
public GameObject enemy;

void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D o) {
    if (o.tag == "CreateEnemy")
        Instantiate (enemy, new Vector3 (5.65f, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);  
}
```

Veja que existe uma variável "enemy" do tipo GameObject, é a variavel no qual arrasto o meu prefab no inspector.

O que eu quero é quando o gatilho for executado, adicionar outros tipos de inimigos e não sempre o mesmo.

O problema é que só sei adicionar inimigos utilizando a maneira descrita acima, que não serve para diferentes tipos de inimigos.

Como faço para adicionar vários tipos de inimigos? Adicionando uma lista do tipo GameObject (em que cada posição possui um prefab que corresponde a um inimigo) e depois sorteando um dos elementos? Se sim, como faço para instanciar um prefab diretamente no código e não pelo inspector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema foi resolvido.

Basta criar uma pasta com o nome "Resources" dentro da pasta "Assets" e organizar os seus recursos, por exemplo, criei a pasta "Prefabs" dentro da pasta "Resources" e arrastei para lá todos os meus prefabs.

Depois no código fiz a seguinte alteração:

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D o) {    
    if (o.tag == "CreateBackground")
        Instantiate(Resources.Load("Prefabs/Enemy"), new Vector3 (5.65f, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
}
```